# hooking on Centos 8 filed and rebooting the system

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I wrote a simple hook that changes the pointer of the sys_call_table and points the execve function to my function the hook work just fine on ubuntu in kernel 4.15 but when I tried it on centos 8 system in kernel 4.18 it filed and rebooting the system.
how can it be done in new kernels?

this is my code:

```
static int lkm_example_init(void)
{
    write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~ 0x10000));

    sys_call_table = (void*)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
    original_call = sys_call_table[__NR_kill];
    sys_call_table[__NR_kill] = our_sys_kill;

    execl = sys_call_table[__NR_execve];

    sys_call_table[__NR_execve] = our_execl;
}
```

Comment: Step 1 is to get the error information which is printed when the kernel crashes.

Comment: In kernel 4.17, the `sys_call_ptr_t` function pointer prototypes (as used in the `sys_call_table[]` entries) changed for the x86_64 architecture, introducing an extra level of indirection in the form of a single `struct pt_regs *` parameter instead of six `unsigned long` parameters. For portability, you need to use the SYSCALL_DEFINEx() macros to define your replacement system call hooks.

Comment: @IanAbbott  can you send an example I have some problem with that for example in what type should be my original_call pointer